# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in views/stock/form.php on line 29

Tags: php, html

My code is working just fine in localhost , but when i upload it to the server, it show this error on spesific line.
This is the error line of code.

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." <?php if(!empty(trim($row->item_name))){ ?> value="<?= $row->item_name ?>"<?php } ?> />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using `empty()` on the `trim()` function.

Try `trim()` before passing the data to the `empty()` function,
Something like this:

```
<?php $item_name=trim($row->item_name); ?>
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control"
   placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." <?php if (!empty($item_name)) {
echo 'value="' . $row->item_name . '"';
} ?> />
```

Also, if it was me, I recommend using a cleaner code:

```
<?php
$item_name=trim($row->item_name);
$value='';
if(!empty($item_name)){
    $value='value="'.$row->item_name.'"';
}
?>
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." <?=$value;?> />
```

Comment: Thank you.
Working great and it makes code more readable.
It's just my bad habit for simple short code.

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control"
   placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." <?php if (!empty(trim($row->item_name))) {
echo 'value="' . $row->item_name . '"';
} ?> />
```

what I have done is changed your

```
<?php if(!empty(trim($row->item_name))){ ?> value="<?= $row->item_name ?>"<?php } ?>
```

to

```
<?php if (!empty(trim($row->item_name))) {
echo 'value="' . $row->item_name . '"';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another approch:

```
<?php if(!empty(trim($row->item_name))){$i_name = $row->item_name;} ?>
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." value="<?php echo $i_name; ?>" />
```

Comment: Sorry for late respond.
It still doesn't working on hosted website, just working on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Assign the value to new variable `value="<?= !empty($ne_variable=trim($row->item_name))?  $row->item_name:'' ?>"`

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="i_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan nama item..." value="<?= !empty($ne_variable=trim($row->item_name))?  $row->item_name:'' ?>" />
```